# Set default page when installed new module

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14

i want to know how to set default page when installing new module.

Like example, My main module is about restaurant ERP, by it's default when i open my module the default page is Restaurant Overview and then i installed reporting sub module with Report Dashboard on it. How to set default page from Restaurant Overview to Report Dashboard when i open restaurant module ?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo permits to set an initial action for every user.
From Settings -> Users and Companies -> Users pick one user.
Move to Preferences tab, and pick desired action in Initial page action field.

Repeat this for every user.